# How do I merge my blender files?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I've made numerous different animations for a wolf, making a different blender file for each. I've just learnt that I should have made them all in the same file and played the animations back to back. Could someone please tell me how to merge the files together or copy the animations across to one file. If I can't do this, could someone please break the news to me and tell me I can't so i can start over on the animations. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File, Append. Choose a blend file, double click to open, then navigate to the Actions you want to append to the current blend file.

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/file.html?highlight=file%20append) for more info.

Comment: I clicked append and clicked the armature actions but it can't notice any change, is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This just appends them to the current file. You'll notice they're loaded when you look at the Action Editor, and select an Armature. You can then select any of the loaded actions to apply to the Armature.

Comment: Where do I find the Action Editor?

Comment: It's part of the Dope Sheet editor. [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/action.html)

Comment: Ok, I've found it. When I click the tab that hovers "Browse Action to be linked" and select the animation I just appended, it switches to a different animation line, how do I make it so they are played right after one another?

Comment: Use the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/index.html), there you can place your actions on a timeline and have them play one after another.

Comment: Ok, I've done it. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Note: The "Append" option under "File" will be grayed out if you are not in Object mode. Also, the manual link is a 404.